# Having trouble getting my math to come out correctly, when reading from a file

Tags: python, file, math

When I do the math in a stand alone program where I manually plug the data in, it comes out correctly:

```
a = ((218 / 313) - 0.3) * 5
b = ((2980 / 313) - 3) * 0.25
c = (23 / 313) * 20
d = 2.375 - ((4 / 313) * 25)

score = ((a+b+c+d) * 100) / 6

print(score)

a1 = ((215 / 321) - 0.3) * 5
b1 = ((2454 / 321) - 3) * 0.25
c1 = (12 / 321) * 20
d1 = 2.375 - ((7 / 321) * 25)

score1 = ((a1+b1+c1+d1) * 100) / 6

print(score1)
```

which gives me the correct answers:

```
Matt Ryan          118.96
Kirk Cousins       93.13
```

The above is how the data should be being pulled from the file.  But every time I run the code the answers are all wrong.  When I run the code the way its suppose to work I get these answers:

```
Matt Ryan          124.23
Kirk Cousins       102.12
```

Below is the main code that produces the wrong answers as shown above (there are more than two but just as an example).

```
import math

def calcA(passA,passC):
    avgA = ((passC / passA) - 0.3) * 5
    return avgA

def calcB(passA,passY):
    avgB = ((passY / passA) - 3) * 0.25
    return avgB

def calcC(passA,td):
    avgC = (td / passA) * 20
    return avgC

def calcD(passA,ints):
    avgD = 2.375 - ((ints / passA) * 0.25)
    return avgD

def main():

    filename = input("Enter the name of your input file: ")
    infile = open(filename,"r")

    name = infile.readline().strip()
    passA = eval(infile.readline())
    passC = eval(infile.readline())
    passY = eval(infile.readline())
    td = eval(infile.readline())
    ints = eval(infile.readline())

    print("Name                   Rating")
    print("-----------------------------")

    while name != "DONE":

        a = calcA(passA,passC)
        b = calcB(passA,passY)
        c = calcC(passA,td)
        d = calcD(passA,ints)

        score = ((a+b+c+d) * 100) / 6

        print(format(name),("       "),format(score,"7.2f"))

        name = infile.readline().strip()
        passA = eval(infile.readline())
        passC = eval(infile.readline())
        passY = eval(infile.readline())
        td = eval(infile.readline())
        ints = eval(infile.readline())

    infile.close()

    print("-----------------------------")
    print("Average Rating")

main()
```

Comment: `calcD` has `* 0.25`, not `* 25`

Comment: Don't use `eval()`, use `float()` to convert a string to a float.

Comment: What @Barmar says, *Never ever* use eval() on user input. Huge disasters are waiting to happen here: the user can trivially cause arbitrary code execution like this. Also, ``float("...")`` is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

*Collecting snippets from comments to get this out of the unanswered queue.*

```
d = 2.375 - ((4 / 313) * 25)
```

does not match

```
avgD = 2.375 - ((ints / passA) * 0.25)
```

as the former multiplies by `25`, the latter by `0.25`.

```
 passA = eval(infile.readline())
```

This is really really bad style. Mostly because if `infile` is a file provided by someone else, that someone can cause you to execute arbitrary code. Install a key logger on your system, delete all your files, install a backdoor or whatever. Even if in this instance it's just you writing that file, never get in the habit of doing things this way, i.e. allowing arbitrary code execution in files that look like data files.

If the input file is just containing some numbers, then using `float(infile.readline().strip())` to convert a number's string representation to its numeric value is both safer and more efficient. Plus it will throw an exception if input format is not as expected, instead of trying to interpret the line as program code instead.